# Make sure every item in list is unique?

Tags: c#, list, filter, unique, hashset

Let's say I have a list of 1 to 10.000.000 items. The type is List. The CustomObj looks like this:

```
class Person 
{
   public string Prename;
   public string Lastname;

   public CustomObj(string pre, string last)
   {
      Prename = pre; 
      Lastname = last;
   }
}
```

I want to make sure, every person in this list is unique. So if I try to add a "Tim Stone" and there already is a "Tim Stone" in the list, the new one will not get added or filtered out.

I tried doing it using the List.Distinct() function to remove the duplicates. Sadly, it does not work so good with custom objects and I ended up getting duplicates.

Could a HashSet be, what I am looking for? If so, how would the implementation look like?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding them to a List first, you could add them to a `HashSet` as you mentioned. Override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. For example, you could do this

```
public class Person  
{
    public string Prename;
    public string Lastname;


    public Person(string pre, string last)
    {
        Prename = pre; Lastname = last;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Person p = obj as Person;

        //can make this check case insensitive using the overload
        return (Prename + Lastname).Equals(p.Prename + p.Lastname);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Prename + Lastname).GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

This way, when you add them to a `HashSet`, duplicates won't be added. If you already have a list, you can use the `HashSet's` constructor overload like this:

```
HashSet<Person> hsPerson = new HashSet<Person>(myExistingList);
```

You'll end up with a `HashSet` of `Person` objects that won't have duplicates.

My implementation above assumes a duplicate is someone that has the same `prename` and `lastname` once they're concatenated but you can change that to what you prefer.

Comment: What happens if `Prename` or `Lastname` change while still in the `HashSet`? According to your `GetHashCode` method, they wont be found.

Comment: I assumed OP was just concerned about adding or filtering a list. If updating whilst in a collection, it may make sense to implement the `IEqualityComparer` interface with a custom way of checking duplication.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the *order* of the elements in your collection, then [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) is the way to go.

Its methods are almost the same as those of `List` since they implement common interfaces such as `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`. Here's a sample:

```
HashSet<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>();
var heko = new Person("heko", "17");
people.Add(heko); // people now contains heko
people.Add(heko); // people still contains only heko since duplicates are not allowed
people.Add(new Person("Nikola", "Dimitroff")); // people contains heko and nikola
```

There are several things to note. Firstly, since `HashSet` doesn't keep the elements in order, you can't get elements by their index i.e. `people[0]` is invalid operation. To enumerate the people in the set use `foreach`.

Secondly, `HashSet` uses the `==` operator and the `GetHashCode` method when comparing items. Be sure to overload them if you consider that `new Person("heko", 17") == new Person("heko", "17")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `HashSet<T>` or any `Distinct` operations with your custom objects, you can make your custom object implement the [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) interface (following all the guidance on that page, including overriding `GetHashCode`). Once that's done, the BCL collections and LINQ operations will behave the way you want them to.

You should be aware that making `GetHashCode` use properties of the class which can be changed can result in very bad things happening (for example, items in a dictionary or set can get "lost"). If you can't make your important properties immutable, you can satisfy your requirement by creating a custom implementation of `IList<T>` which wraps a standard `List<T>` and implement the `Add` method of your collection type like this:

```
public void Add(Person person)
{
   if (!_list.Any(p => p.Prename == person.PreName && p.Lastname == person.Lastname))
   {
      _list.Add(person);
   }
}
```

This solution will be much less efficient, but may save you some puzzling bugs.